# Automatic slashes

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, stripslashes

So I have a dictionary that gets populated with keys and values, the only problem is that when you try to enter a string that has this general outline "blah\stuff" and you try to log it, then the value for that key shows "blah\\stuff." I want it to be "blah\stuff" like how the user inputs it. Anyone know how to fix this?

```
   SMTPPort = "";
"Use SSL" = false;
"User Name_in" = "tia\\voizapp";
"User Name_out" = tia;
isOn = no;
```

Comment: What exactly you want to accomplish? In objective-c a string literal is defined by @"string literal", NSDictionary can be defined like so.      `NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"name" : NSUserName(), @"date" : [NSDate date], @"processInfo" : [NSProcessInfo processInfo] };`    You can find more info under [Objective-C Literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html)

Comment: well yeah obviously,just assume i made my dictionary correct and i know how to put in strings. When my string has a backslash it makes a double backslash automatically

Comment: "User Name_in" is the key in my dictionary and "tia\\voizapp" is my string but that string should be "tia\voizapp"

Comment: As long you use @"" syntax the double slash is removed. If you are using "" syntax strings should be created like + (id)stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)bytes.

Comment: i see, well then my issue is pretty weird then. The string comes from the textfield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like an escaping issue. If you wanted to get a single backslash into an NSString, you'd use a double-backslash:

```
NSString* someString = @"blah\\stuff";
```

Is it possible your code is preserving the double backslash behind the scenes?

Comment: hmm ok, so what if a user inputs the string, they wont know to use double backslashes

Comment: They wouldn't need to. See Bernd Rabe's comment. I'm wondering whether your code is adding the double backslashes, later intending that the strings be loaded into an NSString etc. If you use @ with a string literal, two double backslashes correlates to a single backslash. No problem in that case. If not, you can end up with two double backslashes.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense, it is most likely doing that, thx! Sorry for not posting code, it is huge  and the dictionary is getting values added in a lot of methods